# Android phone number mask for EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, phonenumberutils

I'm developing application for Android. In this app user needs sign up and he needs type phone number. I want make mask for this text field in format like +7 (999) 999-99-99. I've tried use `mPhoneNumberEditText.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());` but it provides only (999) 999-9999 format.
How can I do format which I need?

Comment: Please post your code what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

The most effective way to use a mask on EditText in your Android programs in Android Studio is to use `MaskedEditText` library ([GitHub link](https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask)).
It's a kind of custom EditText with Watcher that allows you to set a hint with different color (if you want if will be available even when user already started to type), mask and it's very easy to use :-)

```
compile 'ru.egslava:MaskedEditText:1.0.5'

<br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText
    android:id="@+id/phone_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    mask:allowed_chars="1234567890"
    mask:mask="+7(###)###-##-##"
    app:keep_hint="true"
    />
```

And that is!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The format you are looking for is used in Russia.
Use the following code for it:

```
String data = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber("9999999999", "RU");
Log.i("Number", data);
```

The first parameter is your number string and second one is the ISO code of the country.

Useful Links: [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#formatNumber(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), [Phone Number formats of different countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers), [ISO code of countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1)

Answer (score 2):

> **This plugin can help:**

https://github.com/pinball83/Masked-Edittext

```
<com.github.pinball83.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/masked_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:mask="+7 (***) ***-**-**"
            app:notMaskedSymbol="*"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing my piece of code with to give you an idea, how could you do it.

I did it for my project a long ago, I hope you could figure out how the following number XXXXXXXXXXXXX converted into XXXXX-XXXXXXX-X in textwatcher

```
 @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int i = et_cnic.getText().toString().length();
            if (i < 6)
                len = 0;
            if (i == 6 && len < 7) {
                len = 7;
                String ss = s.toString();
                String first = ss.substring(0, ss.length() - 1);
                String last = ss.substring(ss.length() - 1);
                et_cnic.setText(first + "-" + last);
                et_cnic.setSelection(et_cnic.getText().length());
            }
            if (i < 14)
                len2 = 0;
            if (i == 14 && len2 < 14) {
                len2 = 14;
                String ss = s.toString();
                String first = ss.substring(0, ss.length() - 1);
                String last = ss.substring(ss.length() - 1);
                et_cnic.setText(first + "-" + last);
                et_cnic.setSelection(et_cnic.getText().length());
            }
        }
```